# UI thread stops working correctly during execution

Tags: java, android, multithreading, user-interface

I am making an Android game using Java. When user clicks a button that starts a thread that does a bunch of shooting and bouncing that goes on for a while with a sleep(20) and this.invalidate() to show it happening in real-time. I am also trying to introduce a daemon thread that would be responsible for animations. I noticed that with introduction of the second thread something in UI thread breaks during program execution. How soon it breaks depends on a number of factors. But as soon as it breaks the following things can be observed:

- code inside activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() { stops being executed.
- when switching to another app and back the action bar and the notification bar no longer disappear. So this code stops executing too:

  ```
  getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(
          View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                  | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                  | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                  | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                  | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                  | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY);
  getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS);
  ```
- closing the app and starting it again results in it freezing with a blank grey screen.

However the following still works: 
* animations still show correctly
* the shoot and bounce still works and show correctly without lag.
* killing the app and starting it again fixes it temporarily.

The following scenarios seem to cause the break during runtime:

1. introduction of the extra animation thread.

   public void animThread()
   {

   ```
   animThread = new Thread ( new Runnable( ) {
       public void run( )
       {

       while(true)
       {
           animation();
       }


       }
   } );

   animThread.setDaemon(true);
   animThread.setPriority(3);
   animThread.start();
   ```

   }

   private void animation()
   {
       if(powerups.isEmpty()==false)
       {
           synchronized (powerups)
           {
               for(PowerUp pw: powerups)
               {
                   if(pw.isActivated()==false) pw.rotate();
               }
           }

   ```
   }

   this.invalidate();


   try {
       if(Units.animPause==true)
       {

           synchronized (Units.animSync) {
               while (Units.animPause) {
                   try {
                       Units.animSync.wait();
                   } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                       System.out.println("interrupt");
                   }
               }
           }

       }
       else {

           Thread.sleep(20);                //delay before next cycle
       }

   } catch (InterruptedException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
   }
   ```

   }

Priority, Daemon, the if statement that checks if the thread should wait don't make a difference. The problem will happen without a single activity.runOnUiThread call.

2. If I call activity.runOnUiThread too frequently from the shooting thread. The same problem will happen even without the animation thread.
   I even replaced all the shooting code with this to test:

   public void testshoot()
   {
       //int count=0;
       while(counter<100)
       {

   ```
       counter++;
       System.out.println("counter: " + counter);
       if(counter % 2 == 0)
       {
           gw.activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
               @Override
               public void run() {
                   System.out.println("game over run");
                   System.out.println("counter: 1: " + counter);
                   gw.activity.findViewById(R.id.GameOver).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                   ((TextView)gw.activity.findViewById(R.id.Score)).setText("Your Score: " + counter);
                   System.out.println("game over run1");
               }
           });
       }

       try {
           if(Units.isPaused==true)
           {
               synchronized (Units.pauseSync) {
                   while (Units.isPaused) {
                       try {
                           Units.pauseSync.wait();
                       } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                           System.out.println("interrupt");
                       }
                   }
               }

           }
           else {

               Thread.sleep(20);                //delay before next cycle
           }

       } catch (InterruptedException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
       }

   }

   counter=0;
   ```

   }

What will happen is the menu will show on the screen and the counter will start to increment correctly until it just stops updating because code inside runOnUiThread stopped being executed because something broke. Making it call less frequently seems to postpone or even eliminate the problem. For example if(counter % 10 == 0)

3. If I combine animation thread from point 1 with calling runOnUiThread from point 2 the problem will appear sooner.

My onPause and onResume:

```
public void onPause()
{
    if(Units.isPaused == false)
    {
        Units.adHocPause=true;
        synchronized (Units.pauseSync) {
            Units.isPaused = true;
        }
    }

    synchronized (Units.animSync) {
        Units.animPause = true;
    }

    super.onPause();
}

@Override
public void onResume(){
    //System.out.println("is paused: " + Units.isPaused);
    if(Units.adHocPause==true)
    {
        Units.adHocPause=false;
        synchronized (Units.pauseSync) {
            Units.isPaused = false;
            Units.pauseSync.notifyAll();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        View menu = findViewById(R.id.Menu);
        menu.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        synchronized (Units.pauseSync) {
            Units.isPaused = true;
        }
    }

    synchronized (Units.animSync) {
        Units.animPause = false;
        Units.animSync.notifyAll();
    }


    getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(
            View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY);

    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS);
    super.onResume();
}
```

I want to understand what exactly happens when something in my app break during runtime, what is it that breaks, what causes it and how can I avoid it. I am interested in making scenario 1 to work. I included scenarios 2 and 3 because hopefully they give a clew what it is that breaks.

Comment: All the results indicates that this is a problem with thread safety. Have you tried using Syncrhonized() blocks on testshoot() or CountDownLatch?

Comment: Looks like I was spawning extra threads. I'm now confused about android's lifecycle. Navigating away using recent or home is supposed to be similar to closing it with back. It stays in memory, resources are loaded etc. However I now realised that when I use home/recent to switch onCreate doesn't get called, but if I use back button and then open it again onCreate does get called. But that's where I load and create everything. I thought its only called if the app was killed outright. Back button didn't kill daemon threads for example.

Comment: I believe, when you press home/recent the app stays in memory, for a while. Then, onStop is called, in which if you re-open, onCreate will be called again. Back button must be similar at the very least. However, what if onCreate is called? Do you have some sort of memory leak? I understand new thread creation. What happens to old ones? Don't they die? You may need to use CountDownLatches on those thread creators. See if that fixes your problem. (I don't know if you already fixed it though)

Comment: According to all diagrams the only way from onStop to onCreate is through the app process killed.(Unlike onStart) But I always get onCreate called after I use Back button. So what was happening is Back button didn't kill daemon threads, but then onCreate was called anyway where I created another thread. I can take care of terminating the threads in onBackPressed manually. Hopefully that fixed my problem. Thanks!